# Descargar PDF php

Tags: php, api, pdf

Tengo este códogo donde descargo un archivo PDF desde una API, sin embargo ademas de descargar el archivo el mismo se guarda en el servidor, y solo deseo que se descargue sin que se quede alojado en el servidor...

```
    $id_factura=$_GET['id_factura'];
    $pdfDowload = $facturapi->Invoices->download_pdf($id_factura); 
    
    $file = $id_factura.'.pdf'; 
    file_put_contents($file, $pdfDowload); 
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"'); 
    header('Expires: 0'); 
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate'); 
    header('Pragma: public'); 
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); readfile($file);
```

Comment: Cuando lo **descargas**, siempre queda alojado en el servidor. Lo _descargas_. Otra cosa es que controles en qué ruta queda, si es una ruta temporal, si lo borras después de usarlo en tu código, etc.

Comment: Comenta todas la líneas que tienen `$file` y pon al final `echo $pdfDownload`. Si es un pdf es mas apropiado que tipo de contenido sea : `application/pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

tengo armado un sistema en el que fuerzo la descarga de archivos. Intenta con el siguiente codigo a ver como resulta, estoy asumiento que $pdfDowload es un archivo pdf.

```
        $id_factura=$_GET['id_factura'];
        $pdfDowload = $facturapi->Invoices->download_pdf($id_factura);            
        
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$pdfDowload);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($pdfDowload);
```